# GitLab CI how to store credentials to docker registry

Tags: docker, encryption, credentials, gitlab-ci, docker-registry

I'd like to have credentials to my registry stored in gitlab (encrypted) and use them to deploy images, what is a proper way to do so? (I'm using external registry, not gitlab container registry)

Comment: Have you tried using gitlab ci variables and docker login in script section?

Comment: Yes, i did, I think there's no other way. Thanks for the reply